# Where does NgRx (or Redux) actually store data?

Tags: redux, ngrx

Obviously it's in client side memory, but what's keeping it there under the hood? LocalStorage? WebStorage?

Answer (score 5):

It's just some Javascript variables.

Here's a tiny version of a Redux store:

```js
function createStore(reducer) {
    var state;
    var listeners = []

    function getState() {
        return state
    }

    function subscribe(listener) {
        listeners.push(listener)
        return function unsubscribe() {
            var index = listeners.indexOf(listener)
            listeners.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }

    function dispatch(action) {
        state = reducer(state, action)
        listeners.forEach(listener => listener())
    }

    dispatch({})

    return { dispatch, subscribe, getState }
}
```

So, `state` is literally just a variable that points to whatever your reducer function returned.

Comment: Ah, so everything that's in the store is wiped out once you close the browser, then?

Comment: Sure.  Again, it's just like any other JS variable.  When you close a tab, that JS runtime environment is wiped away.  If you _do_ want to persist some data and reload it into the newly-created store the next time the user opens that tab again, you need to save it somewhere else like `localStorage`, and pass that into the store as it's initialized.